# C#: DateTime form string

Tags: c#, datetime

So I have this `string:

```
string time = "20201006 10:42:42.925"
```

Which look like valid time format.

And this is what I have try:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(time);
```

And got this error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: You have asked over a 100 questions, please read [ask] and show that you at least pasted that error message in a web search engine and have attempted to solve this yourself. `DateTime.Parse()` accepts a format related to the current culture, but not this particular nonstandard format, so you'll have to provide the format to `(Try)ParseExact()`.

Answer (score -2):

Use TryParse  Method, eg

```
dateTime dt1;
if DateTime.TryParse(time, out dt1)
{
// all good

} else{
// no good
}
```

Comment: Assuming the OP is interested in the actual parsed DateTime value, ending up in the `else` will do them no good.